# Find $A^{10}$, given the characteristic equation of $A$ and using the Cayley-Hamilton method for solving matrices with high powers.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, cayley-hamilton

I'm given the following matrix
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
2.5 & -1 & -1.5\\
1.5 & 0.5 & -1.5\\
0.5 & -1 & 0.5
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Its characteristic equation is $λ^3 - 3.5λ^2 +3.5λ -1$ (e.g. eigenvalues of $2$, $1$, and $0.5$).

How can I find $A^{10}$ using the known facts and a system of equations?

I know that I have to use the Cayley-Hamilton method.

\begin{align}
f(v) &= v^{10} = a + bv + cv^2 \\
f'(v) &= 10v^9 = b + 2cv
\end{align}

So that:
\begin{align}
f(2) &= a + 2b + 4c \\
f'(1) &= b + 2c \\
f(0.5) &= a + 0.5b + 0.25c
\end{align}

I solved for $a$, $b$, and $c$. Then I used the following formula to find $A^{10}$:
$$
A^{10} = a*I + b*A + c*A^2
$$

However, when I compare my answer with Matlab, my answer doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 2):

You know that $A^{10}=aI+bA+cA^2$ for some $a,b,c$.

If $v$ is an eigenvector relative to $2$, then
$$
A^{10}v=2^{10}v=av+2bv+4cv
$$
so
$$
a+2b+4c=2^{10}
$$
Similarly, with the eigenvalue $1$, you get
$$
a+b+c=1
$$
and, with the eigenvalue $1/2$, you get
$$
a+\frac{1}{2}b+\frac{1}{4}c=\frac{1}{2^{10}}
$$